# Ethernet connection doesn't show any device

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1. I've got problem with my Ethernet connection, although the Wifi connection works fine.

I have seen many issues related to the Ethernet connection not working, but I still can't manange to fix it. I tried adding a new connection through the following path:

Edit Connections... > Add > Ethernet > Create... > Device

But it doesn't show any device.

This is the output from `isfconfig -a`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2071511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2071511 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2983682547 (2.9 GB)  TX bytes:2983682547 (2.9 GB)

wlx0025224e5605 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:22:4e:56:05  
          inet addr:192.168.0.15  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::23b2:cd5e:f937:c3a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9262409 (9.2 MB)  TX bytes:1080405 (1.0 MB)
```

This is the output from `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

This is inside /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And this is inside /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for elaborating on the problem a bit more. Please try to install the appropriate closed-source driver from the universe-repos. To do this, simply try the following steps:

Edit your */etc/apt/sources.list* and add:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe
```

afterwards do an update & install:

```
$~ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

If all went well, the module should be loaded and your interface should be visible. To check on that, execute:

```
$~ sudo lsmod | grep r8168; ifconfig -a
```